# ¿Cómo desenfocar solo la imagen de un background-image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una imagen para un fondo del *body* en mi sitio y quiero aplicar un poco de desenfoque, resulta que cuando aplico la propiedad *blur* me desenfoca todos los div y mis *container*, pero no el *body*.

```css
body{
    background-image: url("ruta");
    filter: blur(6px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

También probé agregando con un *class* en *css*, pero no me funciona.

```css
.fondo-body{
    background-image: url("ruta");
    filter: blur(6px);
}
```

```html
<body class="fondo-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar colocandolo en la pseudo `:before` del body, quedando así:

```css
body:before {
  filter: blur(2px);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%; 
  width: 20%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}

.container{
  z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas algo más simple, puedes usar la propiedad **`backdrop-filter`** a tu CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url("ruta");
    backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
}
```

Aquí esta la documentación si gustas: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Nota: Esto requiere el prefijo -webkit- para Safari.